# Adding or removing EventEmitter.call(this) in my Node example doesn't make any difference, why?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js and started learning it.

I came across "EventEmitter" in "events" module in node.

After following the example in EventEmitter documentation I wrote the bolow code,

```
var EventEmitter = require("events");
var util = require("util");

var Ticker = function(){
  var self = this;
  EventEmitter.call(self);

  self.start = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        self.emit("tick");
    },1000);
  }

  self.on("tick",function(){
    console.log("Keep Ticking");
  });
}

util.inherits(Ticker,EventEmitter);

var ticker = new Ticker();
ticker.start();
```

When I run the code

```
node example03.js
```

the output is

```
rahul@ubuntu:~/rahul/NodePractise/EventEmitter$ node example03.js
Keep Ticking
Keep Ticking
Keep Ticking
Keep Ticking
^C
rahul@ubuntu:~/rahul/NodePractise/EventEmitter$
```

Now even if I comment the line

```
//EventEmitter.call(self);
```

The code works fine.

So whats the purpose of the above line and how is its presence important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So whats the purpose of the above line and how is its presence
>   important.

The line of code:

```
EventEmitter.call(self);
```

is so the base class (what you inherited from) can properly initialize it's own instance each time you create a new instance of your derived class.  This is a very important step that should not be left out.

To explain exactly what it is doing, `EventEmitter` is the constructor function of the object you derived from.  `.call(self)` is telling Javascript to call that constructor function and to set the `this` value to the object that was just created (which is pointed to by `self` in your code).  That will end up calling the `EventEmitter` constructor in the same way as `new EventEmitter()` would call it which is what you want.  The only difference here from `new EventEmitter()` is that you're pointing `this` at an instance of your derived object, not at just an `EventEmitter` object.

In all cases of inheritance, you should call the base class constructor so it can properly initialize itself.  But, there may be some types of objects that don't really do much in the constructor so things may happen to work if you leave it out.  Or they may just seem to work, but there will be problems down the road.

---

> Adding or removing EventEmitter.call(this) in my Node example doesn't
>   make any difference, why?

If you look at the [EventEmitter code on Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js), you can see that the `EventEmitter` constructor does this:

```
function EventEmitter() {
  EventEmitter.init.call(this);
}
```

And, the `.init()` method does this:

```
EventEmitter.init = function() {
  this.domain = null;
  if (EventEmitter.usingDomains) {
    // if there is an active domain, then attach to it.
    domain = domain || require('domain');
    if (domain.active && !(this instanceof domain.Domain)) {
      this.domain = domain.active;
    }
  }

  if (!this._events || this._events === Object.getPrototypeOf(this)._events) {
    this._events = {};
    this._eventsCount = 0;
  }

  this._maxListeners = this._maxListeners || undefined;
};
```

So, if you fail to call the parent constructor, there will be several instance variables in the EventEmitter object that are not properly initialized.  What this does to the code is anyone's guess (it would take further code study and testing to know for sure), but it is not a good thing.  Some features might work without this initialization, but it is very likely that other things will not work properly.